# Deviceready won't fire in Cordova-1.9.0 with Android 4.1

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

**------Index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>AmmoAmmo</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script
    src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-1.9.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="samin.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

function onLoad() {
    console.log("1.......onLoad()..........."); 
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady(), false);
}

    // Cordova is loaded and it is now safe to make calls Cordova methods
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {
        console.log("2. -------------onDeviceReady--------------------");
        // Now safe to use the Cordova API
        alert('3. _____________onDeviceReady()-DONE!_____________');
    }

    function saveAmmo(value){

        //testAlert();
        window.localStorage.setItem("selectedAmmo", value);
        alert(value,'_top');

    }
    </script>

</head>
<body onload="onLoad()">
    <div data-role="page" id="homePage" data-theme="a">

        <div data-role="header">
            <a href="index.html" data-icon="info">Help</a>
            <h1>Testing</h1>
            <a href="contact.html" data-icon="info">Contact</a>
        </div>

        <div data-role="content">
            <p>
                <label for="select-choice-0" class="select"></label>
                 <select name="select-choice-0" id="select-choice-0"
                    data-mini="true" onchange="saveAmmo(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)">
                    <option value='null' SELECTED>Select a Ammo</option>
                    <option value='1' >111</option>
                    <option value='2' >222</option>
                </select>
            </p>


        </div>
        <div class="ui-grid-a">
            <div class="ui-block-a" align="center">
                <img src="images/22-250_rem_1.jpeg" data-theme="c"/>
            </div>
            <div class="ui-block-b" align="center">
                <img src="images/22-250_rem_1.jpeg" data-theme="c"/>
            </div>
        </div>


        <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
            <div data-role="navbar">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="index.html" class="ui-btn-
           active">Ammo</a></li>
                    <li><a href="testing1.html">Test1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="testing2.html">Test2</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>


</body>

</html>
```

This is exactly the same situation than in Cordova docs:
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.9.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#deviceready

Everything else is working but this is coming to be a real showstopper, because I need this when reading data from localstorage. Should I believe the documentation or not?

**--------Plugins.xml:**

```
<plugins>
<plugin name="App" value="org.apache.cordova.App"/>
<plugin name="Geolocation" value="org.apache.cordova.GeoBroker"/>
<plugin name="Device" value="org.apache.cordova.Device"/>
<plugin name="Accelerometer" value="org.apache.cordova.AccelListener"/>
<plugin name="Compass" value="org.apache.cordova.CompassListener"/>
<plugin name="Media" value="org.apache.cordova.AudioHandler"/>
<plugin name="Camera" value="org.apache.cordova.CameraLauncher"/>
<plugin name="Contacts" value="org.apache.cordova.ContactManager"/>
<plugin name="File" value="org.apache.cordova.FileUtils"/>
<plugin name="NetworkStatus" value="org.apache.cordova.NetworkManager"/>
<plugin name="Notification" value="org.apache.cordova.Notification"/>
<plugin name="Storage" value="org.apache.cordova.Storage"/>
<plugin name="Temperature" value="org.apache.cordova.TempListener"/>
<plugin name="FileTransfer" value="org.apache.cordova.FileTransfer"/>
<plugin name="Capture" value="org.apache.cordova.Capture"/>
<plugin name="Battery" value="org.apache.cordova.BatteryListener"/>
<plugin name="SplashScreen" value="org.apache.cordova.SplashScreen"/>
```

**-------Manifest.xml---------**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.mycordova.hellocordova"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14" />

<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:resizeable="true"
    android:smallScreens="true" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".HelloCordovaActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_hello_cordova" 
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
</application>
```

**-------Activity.java----------**

```
package com.mycordova.hellocordova;

import android.R;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;
import org.apache.cordova.*;

public class HelloCordovaActivity extends DroidGap {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
    }

}
```

**--------Log:**

```
07-16 10:23:12.878: D/DroidGap(637): onMessage(onPageStarted,file:///android_asset/www/index.html)
07-16 10:23:13.848: D/chromium(637): Unknown chromium error: -6
07-16 10:23:22.388: D/CordovaLog(637): 1.......onLoad()...........
07-16 10:23:22.388: D/CordovaLog(637): file:///android_asset/www/index.html: Line 16 : 1.......onLoad()...........
07-16 10:23:22.398: I/Web Console(637): 1.......onLoad()........... at file:///android_asset/www/index.html:16
07-16 10:23:22.398: D/CordovaLog(637): 2. -------------onDeviceReady--------------------
07-16 10:23:22.408: D/CordovaLog(637): file:///android_asset/www/index.html: Line 23 : 2. -------------onDeviceReady--------------------
07-16 10:23:22.408: I/Web Console(637): 2. -------------onDeviceReady-------------------- at file:///android_asset/www/index.html:23
07-16 10:23:22.789: I/Choreographer(637): Skipped 44 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-16 10:23:31.608: E/CordovaWebView(637): CordovaWebView: TIMEOUT ERROR!
07-16 10:23:31.608: D/Cordova(637): CordovaWebViewClient.onReceivedError: Error code=-6 Description=The connection to the server was unsuccessful. URL=file:///android_asset/www/index.html
07-16 10:23:31.638: D/DroidGap(637): onMessage(onReceivedError,{"errorCode":-6,"url":"file:\/\/\/android_asset\/www\/index.html","description":"The connection to the server was unsuccessful."})
07-16 10:23:31.869: I/Choreographer(637): Skipped 55 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-16 10:23:31.869: D/SoftKeyboardDetect(637): Ignore this event
07-16 10:23:31.995: D/dalvikvm(637): GC_CONCURRENT freed 236K, 4% free 8186K/8519K, paused 27ms+64ms, total 279ms
07-16 10:23:32.788: I/Choreographer(637): Skipped 128 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-16 10:26:00.398: D/DroidGap(637): onDestroy()
07-16 10:26:00.398: D/CordovaWebView(637): >>> loadUrlNow()
07-16 10:26:00.398: D/CordovaWebView(637): >>> loadUrlNow()
07-16 10:26:00.489: E/WindowManager(637): Activity com.mycordova.hellocordova.HelloCordovaActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@41232338 that was originally added here
07-16 10:26:00.489: E/WindowManager(637): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.mycordova.hellocordova.HelloCordovaActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@41232338 that was originally added here
07-16 10:26:00.489: E/WindowManager(637):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:374)
07-16 10:26:00.489: E/WindowManager(637):   at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:292)
07-16 10:26:00.489: E/WindowManager(637):   at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:224)
07-16 10:26:00.489: E/WindowManager(637):   at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:149)
07-16 10:26:00.489: E/WindowManager(637):   at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:547)
07-16 10:26:00.489: E/WindowManager(637):   at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:277)
07-16 10:26:00.489: E/WindowManager(637):   at android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.show(AlertDialog.java:932)
07-16 10:26:00.489: E/WindowManager(637):   at org.apache.cordova.CordovaChromeClient.onJsAlert(CordovaChromeClient.java:120)
07-16 10:26:00.489: E/WindowManager(637):   at android.webkit.CallbackProxy.handleMessage(CallbackProxy.java:572)
07-16 10:26:00.489: E/WindowManager(637):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-16 10:26:00.489: E/WindowManager(637):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-16 10:26:00.489: E/WindowManager(637):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
07-16 10:26:00.489: E/WindowManager(637):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-16 10:26:00.489: E/WindowManager(637):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-16 10:26:00.489: E/WindowManager(637):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
07-16 10:26:00.489: E/WindowManager(637):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
07-16 10:26:00.489: E/WindowManager(637):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Cheers,
Sami

Comment: Yes you should believe it.... Its working in 4.1... Post your error logs and your exact code... I mean Index.html, Activity.java, plugins.xml andd AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: I deleted the line: alert('3. _____________onDeviceReady()-DONE!_____________'); And now it is working?? In next page I can't get a log at all, I mean testing1.html. This is the only line what I got: 07-16 12:21:17.388: D/DroidGap(1135): onMessage(onPageFinished,file:///android_asset/www/index.html#/android_asset/www/testing1.html)
07-16 12:21:19.548: I/Choreographer(1135): Skipped 111 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it is taking too long to load the main page. You should pull those 3 jQuery files and package them with your app instead of having them loaded remotely.

Comment: That was it! I have macbook Pro with 8 Gb and still that emulator is very slow! I wondered why I couldn't see my console.log()-texts at all, but now it is working fine too. BTW, I added jquery.js and jqm.js and css-files to my local folder and now images are missing from buttons etc but there are not in images folder inside the jqm.zip? Where the heck they are?

Comment: Btw, why it is doing so that it drops log-lines from the console if it is too busy? That was really annoying. IN second page there wasn't even a line of concole.log. Any idea how to make emulator faster?

Answer (score 0):

Everything else is fine

Use

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
```

instead of

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

As well as remove **screenSize** from manifest file like this

> android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden">